# Hyperlink image not displaying in email body when user doesn't have access to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, picture

`https` hyperlink images are not displaying on email body, but `http` hyperlink images are displaying on email body.

My SharePoint site is secured (`https://site//sitimages/siteassets/test.jpg`).

How can I display the image on email body even for userswithout access to the SharePoint site?